# What is the technical name for this type of passive: "I am seen"

Tags: passive-voice

For example,

> I am seen, therefore I am
>
> [*The American Journal of Forensic Medicine and Pathology:* June 2019 - Vol 40  Iss 2 - p196](https://journals.lww.com/amjforensicmedicine/Citation/2019/06000/I_Am_Seen,_Therefore_I_Am__Considerations_on_the.24.aspx)

or:

> I was seen entering the bank.

I know that these are passive constructs but I want to know the technical term that describes them (Pseudo-passive?)

Comment: It's normal passive voice. _They saw me_ is passivized to _I was seen._

Comment: By comparison with the stative original ('I think, therefore I am'), it's arguably the stative passive ('I am often seen nowadays', cf 'The dog is fed [regularly and well]') rather than the dynamic passive ('The dog is fed [now; we can leave him in the garden for a few hours.]' See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_voice). // "I am seen; I will soon be captured" is the dynamic passive here (but sounds Shakespearean).

Comment: "I am seen" is called present simple passive here and "I was seen" is the past simple https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/passives Perhaps you need to be a bit more specific about what kind of passive you're differentiating it from.